# compiler warning: Data Argument Not Used by Format String

Tags: objective-c, string

I have copied the code below from an example project but receive the warning "Data Argument Not Used by Format String". In the project I copied from, it was adding a random number to the end of each quote / entry. I don't need this, and imagine this has something to do with it.

Can anyone advise how I can fix?

dvent

```
(IBAction)button:(id)sender {
int r = arc4random() % 2;
NSString *text;
switch (r) {
    case 1:
        text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain", r];
        break;
    case 2:
        text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"I think therefore I am", r];
        break;
}
self.label.text = text;
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Comment: Read the error. Then look at your calls to `stringWithFormat:`. It's pretty clear.

Comment: Also, *read the documentation* of that method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR data argument not used by format string on mySLComposerSheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621430/error-data-argument-not-used-by-format-string-on-myslcomposersheet)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to format the strings with `r`, then simply do:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    int r = arc4random() % 2;
    NSString *text;
    switch (r) {
        case 1:
            text = @"The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain";
            break;
        case 2:
            text = @"I think therefore I am";
            break;

    }
    self.label.text = text;
}
```

Only use `stringWithFormat:` when you actually need to format a string.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. I'm new to all this!